# Simple select all columns of min value -> error

Tags: sql, oracle, min

I'd want a query to fetch all columns of a tuple according to a column's lowest value in the table:

```
SELECT *, MIN(Opened) FROM Account
```

And for some reason this throws an error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

This is basic stuff in my opinion, coming from SQLite, but Oracle is new to me.

I created a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE Account (
    Act_id INTEGER,
    Opened DATE,
    Balance NUMBER(10,2),
    CONSTRAINT act_pk PRIMARY KEY(act_id)
)
```

If I enter any other column name (e.g. `SELECT balance, MIN(opened)`), it gives another error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

According to [this](http://www.learncertification.com/study-material/select-all-columns-in-oracle-sql) tutorial at least the `*` notation is in Oracle. And the `MIN` works by itself. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is "broken" with respect to the syntax that you learned.  It is the only database that returns the entire row of the minimum or maximum in such a case.  There are simple ways to do this, so I'm not sure why the designers felt the need to include that particular (mis)feature.

Just use `order by` and `rownum` if you want one row:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*
      from account a
      order by opened asc
     ) a
where rownum = 1;
```

If you want all rows with the minimum value, use a subquery:

```
select a.*
from account a
where a.opened = (select min(a2.opened) from account a2);
```

Comment: So this is not a feature in Oracle?

Comment: @Felix . . . It is brokenness in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

When you're asking for BALANCE and MIN(OPENED) you need to specify a GROUP BY, as in

```
SELECT BALANCE, MIN(OPENED)
  FROM ACCOUNT
  GROUP BY BALANCE
```

Earlier you said "I'd want a query to fetch all columns of a tuple according to a column's lowest value in the table". My interpretation of this is that you need a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ACCOUNT
  WHERE OPENED = (SELECT MIN(OPENED) FROM BALANCE)
```

Or perhaps you meant you wanted all the columns from ACCOUNT, along with the min value of OPENED for the entire table. In that case I'd suggest a CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT *
  FROM ACCOUNT
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(OPENED) AS MIN_OPENED FROM ACCOUNT)
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Okay, I should have been explicit about the fact that `balance` was also an attribute of `Account`. Or perhaps that's a typo in your second code: `FROM BALANCE`